# Wordpress in a server farm with a CDN

Tags: iis, cdn, wordpress

I have setup a wordpress multisite blog that is load balanced over 5 servers (we're expecting a lot of traffic). This is in windows and using IIS 7

One issue we had was the wp-content folder and synching that with all servers.

I attempted to move the wp-content dir to a shared drive and then use a virtual dir in IIS, but this did not seem to work, I followed the instructions here (http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) ... But could not get the blog to work when wp-content was on a different drive than the actual blog.

Therefore we decided to use vice versa to synch the folders.

Now I am being asked to utilize a CDN we have, limelight (not amazon s3, so I cannot use that plugin) to host our images. I want to somehow synch this CDN with wordpress and then utilize some sort of plugin to rewrite the URL's so that they point to the CDN.

I should also add that this blog is updated by non technical people, therefore asking them upload files directly to the CDN is not really an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the codex instructions for offloading image uploads in multisite just... no.

I know you won't be using the amazons3 plugins, but it *does* work with multisite, and the best I can tell you (becasue there are no specifics docs for this yet) is to have a look at that plugin, see how they do it, adapt for your use.